# Why I can't I set an attribute on an OpenAI Gym environment directly

Tags: python, openai-gym

So I am running into an interesting bug when writing a custom OpenAI gym environment. The code below is the minimal environment I can write that reproduces the bug:

```py
import gym

class TestEnv(gym.Env):
    obs = 3

    def set_obs(self, obs):
        self.obs = obs

    def reset(self):
        return self.obs

    def step(self, a):
        return self.obs, 0, False, None

gym.register('TestEnv-v0', 
             entry_point=f'{__name__}:TestEnv',
             max_episode_steps=1000)

env = gym.make('TestEnv-v0')
print(env.reset())
print(env.obs)
env.obs = 5
print(env.reset())
print(env.obs)
env.set_obs(8)
print(env.reset())
print(env.obs)
```

```
3
3
3
5
8
5
```

For some reason, there is a difference between calling `set_obs` and setting the `obs` attribute directly! I have never applied the pattern of a setter function in Python (it smells of Java too much), but here I have to use it so that the new `obs` is actually taken into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register an environment with `gym.register` and a `max_episode_steps` parameter, OpenAI Gym automatically wraps your environment into a `TimeLimit` object that will make sure that after `max_episode_steps` the environment returns `done=True`. Gym wrappers can forward function calls (i.e. `set_obs`) to the unwrapperd environment, but they don't forward attributes. So `env.obs = 5` sets the `obs` attribute on an instance of `TimeLimit` instead of `TestEnv` instance

Comment: I was running various tests to provided as much context as possible for the stackoverflow question and, while doing that, accidentally solved the issue :)